# Display route between two points on map with mapkit :ios7

Tags: mapkit, ios7

I want to display point to point route between two points on map with in my app. I am using `MKDirectionsRequest` for this.I am trying to find route between pune to mumbai.I am  getting an error as a response.

**Error message :**

```
Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo=0x9d80dd0 {
NSLocalizedFailureReason=A route to the nearest road cannot be determined., NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available, MKDirectionsErrorCode=6, MKErrorGEOError=-403
}
```

Is `MKDirectionsRequest`  for showing route on Maps app only?
How can I find point to point route between two points in iOS7 without using Google API or any routing app?

Can you please help me out regarding the same.
Looking forward for any reference link or sample code from your end.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally i found solution of my question. MKDirectionsRequest is the right api to find route between two points. It seems Apple has not added route feature for India yet. I tried for other country and it worked for me.

Comment: :: I think they have added route feature for India now. But i am still getting the "A route to the nearest road cannot be determined". Any idea.

Comment: It's **2016** and I am still getting the same error. Just check out this link, http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions it says that direction route is still not available for India. Maybe Tim Cook ask Apple for this as he's visiting in India? :)

Answer (score 6):

Apple map directions feature available countries list is in [this](http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions) link.

Please check the link before implement the directions.

Comment: India Still missing :(