# Can not draw path between two location on MKMapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to draw a Route from current source to Destination and in Direction completion handler , i am getting error

**Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available"**

I am using iOS 7 right now.

Here is my Code

```
MKDirectionsRequest *DirectionRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
MKPlacemark *QiblaPlace = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.4166667, 39.81666670000004) addressDictionary:nil];
[DirectionRequest setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
[DirectionRequest setDestination:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:QiblaPlace]];
DirectionRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;
DirectionRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes=YES;
MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:DirectionRequest];
[direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
    } else {

        routeDetails = response.routes.lastObject;
        for (MKRoute *route in response.routes) {
            [_routeMapview addOverlay:routeDetails.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
        }
    }
}];
```

Thanks for Help.

Comment: Apple provided an api which doesn't work.

Comment: Same Question : 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035752/display-route-between-two-points-on-map-with-mapkit-ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035752/display-route-between-two-points-on-map-with-mapkit-ios7)

Comment: what is your current location?  Apple does not support rout draw feature for all countries